# SML recursive programming with String.substring

Tags: recursion, sml

I am trying to write a program that takes two strings `s1` and `s2` as arguments. The function should check whether `s2` contains `s1` and if it does, the program should write the position in `s2` at which the first letter of `s1` occurs.

I want to check: `String.substring(s2, size s2 - size s1, size s1) = s1`.
And I then need to do a recursion on `(size s2 - 1)` so that `s2` gets smaller by one after each comparison and thereby "move the `s1`" comparison of `s2` one letter to the left.

I have no problems with recursions like:

```
fun recurison 0 = 0
  | recurison n = n + (n - 1)
```

But when i shall interact with other functions or `String.substring` it feels messy. How should I think when I'm trying to write some recursive stuff? Can you give me a hint on the problem? I love to come up with the solutions myself but need help to point out the right road.

Answer (score 3):

First, there is already the function `String.isSubstring : string -> string -> bool` which does what you want. But since you are interested in implementing such a function yourself recursively you just have to think about the following:

1. What is the base-case (i.e., when does the recursion end)?
2. What is the step-case (i.e., how to get a solution from a smaller solution)?

Since in your description you started to check for substrings from the right and then move to the left, the base-case is when you arrive at the leftmost position (i.e., 0). As for the step-case, after you checked position `i` you have to check position `i - 1`.

First you might start with a function that handles the case of checking position `i`.

```
fun substringat s1 s2 i =
  if size s1 + i > size s2 then false
  else String.substring (s2, i, size s1) = s1;
```

Then the skeleton for the recursion

```
fun substringfrom s1 s2 i =
  if i < 0 then ~1
  else if substringat s1 s2 i then i
  else substringfrom s1 s2 (i - 1);
```

Finally we initialize everything appropriately

```
fun substring s1 s2 = substringfrom s1 s2 (size s2 - 1);
```

To avoid some unnecessary checks we could combine all this to

```
 fun substring s1 s2 =
   let
     val l1 = size s1;
     val l2 = size s2;

     fun substringat s1 s2 i =
       if l1 + i > l2 then false
       else String.substring (s2, i, l1) = s1;

     fun substringfrom s1 s2 i =
       if i < 0 then ~1
       else if substringat s1 s2 i then i
       else substringfrom s1 s2 (i - 1);
   in
     substringfrom s1 s2 (l2 - 1)
   end
```